# Sort a List of Maps using a field from the value object

Tags: java

Looking for a solution using Java version 7 and below.

I have the following list of maps.

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Person>> stuff = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is Person class

```
class Person{
    private String name;
    private int order;

    // get set
}
```

I want to sort the list "stuff" based on Person's order. How can I do this? I was planning on implementing Comparable on the Person class and write the logic for comparison.

But how do I sort it since the Person object is held as a value in a map which in turn is held in a list. For me to sort a Map, I was thinking maybe I could consider a TreeMap. Then again I am not sure if I am over complicating things.

I need to keep that structure of a List holding a Map of keys as Strings and values as Person. Appreciate any input on this. Thanks.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks good to know there is this solution in 8. Looking for another option in version 7 and less.

Comment: Oops, missed that. Btw, you keep mentioning maps, but there's no map in your code.

Comment: @shmosel List<Map.Entry<String, Person>>

Comment: An Entry is not a Map.

Comment: Hm guess I am using wrong terms here. I want to sort the list using the Entry's order's value.

Comment: Short answer - you'll need to write a `Comparator<Entry<?,Person>>` which does the required comparison on its enclosed `Person` object, then pass that to the `sort` method.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Think I get your point. But is there a reason to go for ?mark instead of String for the key?

Comment: Just to make it slightly more useful.  You're not using the `String`ness of the key, so why insist that the key has to be `String`?  In fact, you should probably make it `Comparator<Entry<?, ? extends Person>>` for the same reason.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Thanks make sense for some re-usability I suppose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just create a Comparator that compares the desired fields:

```
Collections.sort(stuff, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Person>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Person> entry1, Map.Entry<String, Person> entry2) {
        return Integer.compare(entry1.getValue().getOrder(), entry2.getValue().getOrder());
    }
});
```

Once you're on Java 8, this becomes much easier:

```
stuff.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getValue().getOrder()));
```

Comment: Got to say I love the Java 8 approach, but yes this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @kang Are you using Guava by any chance?

Comment: The project does use Guava.